# How can I find out the array position of an object by searching the array?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array like this:

```
var array1 = 
[
  {"phraseId":"abc",
  "keyword":"bb",
  "posId":1},
  {"phraseId":"def",
  "keyword":"bb",
  "posId":1},
]
```

How can I find out that the object with phraseId of "def" has the 2nd position?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Why you can not use a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use native JavaScript **[`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)** method.

```js
var array1 = [{
  "phraseId": "abc",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, {
  "phraseId": "def",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, ];

var pos = array1.findIndex(function(v) {
  // set your condition for finding object             
  return v.phraseId == 'def';
  // add `1` since you want to count from `1`            
}) + 1;

console.log("Position of the object " + pos);
```

---

For older browser [check polyfill option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var array1 = [{
  "phraseId": "abc",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, {
  "phraseId": "def",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, ];

var pos = array1.findIndex(v => v.phraseId == 'def') + 1;

console.log("Position of the object " + pos);
```

Comment: I did not know that `findIndex` was an official ECMAScript 6 thing. Neat.

Comment: I think this solution better than  `.map()` because `findIndex()` it's native JS method returns an index in the array unlike `.map` wich used for array iteration. Interesting to see some benchmarks of this two methods.

Comment: Since we're using the latest cool stuff, why not write it the easy way: `var pos = array1.findIndex(v => v.phraseId === 'def');`

Answer (score 6):

You could map your object and only return the target field, and then use the built in `indexOf` to get the position:

```
array1.map(item => item.phraseId).indexOf('def')
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but this results in 2 iterations of the array as well as the allocation of more memory for the 2nd mapped array, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It works this way :

```
array1.forEach((elem, index) => {if (elem.phraseId === "def")
   console.log("index = " + index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your key is know (that you know you are looking for a `phraseId` always) then you can simply iterate through the array with a normal `for` loop if you are using "traditional" JS, or with a `forEach` if you are using ES6. Here's the simple `for` implementation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ){
    if(array[i].phraseId === 'def') {
    // we know "i" is the index, so do something...
    }
}
```

To make it more generic so you can search any array for any key, make a function of it that returns the index:

```
function whatIndex (arr, key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if( arr[i][key] === val ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```